# Json; how can I return my res array of MongoDB Models to Router's .get, as json? (Node js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb

I can successfully connect, query & find all of the files that I want from my database, according to my model.

But I can't actually return them as JSON yet... so my question is, how can I return this following result (console.log of res):

[image: Console log of res]

Into JSON for my get request?

My model with most vars snipped for brevity:

```
const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fileName: { type: String },
  versionData: [
    {
      versionID: { type: Number, required: false
    }
  ]
});
```

This is my main code where I am trying to return my res as JSON so that my Get request can be properly processed and display the results. I've tried returning JSON.stringify(res), but that didn't seem to work.

```
// Controller code
findAll = function() {
  File.find({}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      // Res is populated successfully
      console.log(res);
      return res.json(); // JSON.stringify(res)
    }
  });
};
```

Router:

```
// Return all results
router.get("/findAll", ctrlFile.findAll);
```

Thank you

Comment: So you're getting "res" as a valid array of objects, right? And the findAll function is your request handler? Have you tried running the server, are you getting errors or is your get route simply not responding?

Comment: try this :  return res.json( { result } );

Comment: Hey thanks for the response fellahs. Yeah, res is a valid array and findAll is my request handler. The arrays are returned properly, and when I get the route on something like Postman, on my server  I end up with an error that goes something like: 
Code: `return res.json({result});` and the error:
`TypeError: res.json is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I got this working by changing:

```
findAll = function() {
  File.find({}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      return res.json();
    }
  });
};
```

To:

```
findAll = (req, res) => {
  File.find({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      return res.json({ result });
    }
  });
};
```